# Is there a way where dispersion can be calculated for a function that does not have variance?

Tags: statistics

Is there a way (or particular examples) how dispersion can be calculated for a function that does not have variance (for example lorentzian)? Or maybe a valid approxiamtion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the range or interquartile range (IQR) of a sample. Or the IQR of the distribution.

For example, Student's t distribution with 1 degree of freedom is a Cauchy (or to physicists Lorenzian) distribution. Below I generate a sample of size $n = 10$ from this distribution and find its range and IQR.

```
x = rt(10, 1)
sort(x)
## -10.62145626  -7.04110168  -2.46458565  -1.70927093  -0.18266706
##  -0.04759129   0.37295424   0.74003646   0.92920488  14.49773186
max(x) - min(x)
## 25.11919
IQR(x)
## 2.924023
```

Below is a graph of the density function, with vertical red lines at the lower
and upper quartiles. The IQR of the distribution is 2; half of the probability in this distribution lies between the quartiles at $\pm 1.$ Notice the heavy
tails, which cause the 'infinite' variance.

[image]

See the Wikipedia article on 'Cauchy' distribution. The scale parameter $\gamma$ is another way to express the dispersion of this distribution.